# SingleConnectionFactory - class not found Spring 4.0.5

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm upgrading an application from 3.2.6-RELEASE to 4.0.5-RELEASE. I've upgraded all the Maven dependencies and the application is building.

However, when I run it, I get the following stacktrace.

```
Apr 23, 2015 2:30:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.spring.framework.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jms/connection/SingleConnectionFactory102
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.spring.chaining.handler.interceptor.ChainingHandlerInterceptor.postProcessBeanFactory(ChainingHandlerInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:177)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory102
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    ... 20 more
```

The same code works fine in the 3.2.6-RELEASE. Any ideas?

Edit: SingleConnection seems to be defined already in application-context.xml

```
 <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Have you actually read the stack trace? It says `SingleConnectionFactory102` not found, not `SingleConnectionFactory`. Quite a different class and support for JMS 1.0.2 has been dropped.

Comment: Cheers. I can't find that class being used in the application. I'll keep digging. Does Apache CXF use this as I was talking with a colleague who said it may do (currently using version 2.7.11 on that, but planning to upgrade to 3.0.4)

Comment: I've investigated a bit more. It seem like it is CXF. I tried to upgrade to 3.0.4 but I get errors with Spring 3.2.6 dependencies. I was able to upgrade to 2.7.15, which seems to be the same. The SingleConnectionFactory102 seems to be called from here.

Answer (score 3):

The class `org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory102` was removed in Spring 4. Use `org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory` instead.

Comment: I've just found the only reference to this class in the application-config.xml

It's already defined as  <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactory"/>
    </bean>